# Use TRUNC() in ADD CONSTRAINT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, date, constraints, primary-key

Is it possible to use the `trunc(date)` function in oracle 11 in `alter table` -> `add constraint`  statement?

```
ALTER TABLE customers
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_name PRIMARY KEY (name, trunc(birth_date))
```

EDIT: The reason I am asking is that it does not work - the error message is ORA-00904 invalid identifier, so:

How can I have only the date part of a DATE column in my primary key?

Comment: Try it and let us know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy enough to test.  The answer appears to be "no".  Instead, you could do something like this:

```
primary key (name, birth_date)
check birth_date = trunc(birth_date)
```

These two constraints would have the same effect.

Or, create a unique functional index:

```
create unique index idx_customers_name_birthdate on customers(name, trunc(birth_date));
```

This has essentially the same effect in terms of preventing duplicates.  Also declare both columns `NOT NULL` (as would be required for a primary key).